# How to using a key to unlock my hyundai i20 locked with the push button fob

Tags: hyundai, key, fob, i20

I had 2 key fobs with 3 buttons. One fob got broken and I replaced it with a key. The key works but when the car has been locked by the fob and the alarm activated the alarm is not deactivated when the key is used to unlock and I open the door which sets off the alarm. How do I use the key to turn off the alarm?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What year of i20 is it? Does it have the "smart key"?

Comment: It is a 2013 model and does have a smart key. Its actually my wife's car and she has the smart fob, mine broke so I bought a key which works the doors and starts the engine but can't remember how to open the door without setting off the alarm.